# connecting computer to a mobile phone - reading sms and use it?

Tags: sms

I've absolutely no idea if this is possible and how it would work.

is it possible to give users a phonenumber where they should send an sms to. 
e.g. the sms contains

name
some code

- i want to track how many sms are sent to this number.
- i want to read the sms text and use both nodes

they weird way i imagine this: i buy a prepaid simcard from any phone provider, i plug the simcard into any device (sim-reader :) ) connected to my computer. my computer is ONLINE. so my computer is kind of transformed to a mobile phone. some software is able to retrieve those sms and i can use the data in it.

is that even possible, if yes HOW?

Comment: Your step - any device/sim-reader - has to be a GSM modem for any of this to work.  Your computer is still not the phone (the GSM modem is) but you will have access to this device via AT (modem) commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use e.g. [gammu](http://wammu.eu/) to send and receive SMS from a cellphone connected to your computer - essentially creating a SMS gateway. I've succesfully used it in the past in this setup (newer phones have serial port emulation through USB, for older ones you need a model-specific serial-to-phone cable):

```
my program <-> database/textfiles <-> gammu <-> serial port <-> cellphone
```

The operation was as follows:

- gammu ran in the command line/daemon mode, with a watchdog script restarting it (and the cellphone) if the cellphone became unresponsive (this was a really old phone; a watchdog is probably not necessary with anything > 2006)
- gammu polled the cellphone for new messages, those were store into a "received" table in the database.
- gammu also polled an "outgoing" table in the database for messages I wanted to send, and sent them through the cellphone.
- my program was a web frontend for reading the incoming messages or inserting the outgoing ones.

(Gammu has an API to interface with the cellphone directly, without the database; I decided to keep the backend and frontend parts separate, and since the frontend was using the database for other things anyway, it was easiest to go that way; also, I was using an old phone for this, and needed the frontend to run even if the cellphone wasn't responding)

Answer (score 3):

There are several possibilities listed [here](http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=sms). But it depends on the phone you are using. Symbian, iOS, Android, Windows Mobile. But basically it is possible using a [GSM Modem](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Send_and_Read_SMS.aspx).